# Do 'composer dump-autoload' with git

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I stumble upon across this note in README of one of the project in github

```
Run the command below when you just update your code (switch branch, merge/rebase, etc.):

composer dump-autoload
```

Why? From what I know dump-autoload just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project.

Comment: Can you add a link to the project?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea because if you update your code via Git usually the `vendor` folder is excluded from Git. So if updating your code e.g. introduces a new class, this class isn't automatically in your `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`. So running a `composer dump-autoload` will regenerate this list.

Comment: but this is tedious, I often switch between branches

Comment: I think this would only be necessary if these branches are different in their list of classes. Probably this was only a suggestion and was more meant like: "run a `composer dump-autoload` to make definitely sure everything works correctly". Most times I personally do not run a `dump-autoload` on a branch switch but if I run into any problems after a switch the first I do is a `dump-autoload` to be sure that this is not my problem.